# how can i change all sprites' image in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Please look at following code

```
thesprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",s]];
thesprite.position = ccp(point.x, point.y);
[self addChild:thesprite];
[_targets addObject:thesprite];//here _targets is NSMutableArray type
```

I use the code to add ten sprites in _targets, and now I want to update all sprites' images, I use code like following

```
[thesprite setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"newImg.png"]];
```

but it only changes the last sprite's image, so how can I do?

Comment: Try the same thing with loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for (CCSprite * sprite in _targets) {
    [sprite setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"newImg.png"]];
}
```